# How can include image link within the div tag

Tags: html

I am working with an html code. I am trying to make image as a hyperlink.But it works only without the div tag.How can i include image link within the div tag?

Here is the code i am using

```
 <div class="image">

     <a href=""><img src="images/01 (22).jpg" width="360" height="200" alt=""></a>

 </div>
```

Thanks..

Comment: post your css for div.image class. and check if theimg src path is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `DIV` inside link (`a`);

```
<a href=""> 
<div class="image">
<img src="images/01 (22).jpg" width="360" height="200" alt=""> 
</div>
</a>
```